PL330 DMA mem to mem transfer test failed
When I use Arm's DMA pl330 controller，I found a problem.
When I test mem to mem transfer configured the incrementing of the source address and the incrementing of the destination address，it will success
but if i configure the fixed of the source address or the fixed of the destination address,it will failed
Logically, I just needto set the corresponding bit in the CCR register to zero and write it down. When I read the register value, it's also normal.
However, it triggers an exception interrupt，I read the corresponding registers by reading them.configure the fixed of the source address will result in read_err,configure the fixed of the destination address will result in write_err.

I found a similar problem on the Internet, but there is no specific solution or reason to explain, and the official manual does not explicitly say that this method is not supported, what is the reason for this problem?
